# sudo yum remove php linux in aws

Tags: linux, php, amazon-ec2, aws

When I was trying to upgrade PHP version in amazon web server I got this kind of error. I'm trying to up upgrade PHP version 5.6 to 7.0 in amazon web server and I am using to putty to upgrade.

```
[root@cpanel ec2-user]# sudo yum remove PHP

Loaded plugins: priorities, universal-hooks, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: PHP
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: If you were trying to upgrade why would you want to remove? Just upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

we should give proper package name.First check which version of php installed.

`rpm -qa php*`

check the package installed and remove it.

`yum remove rh-php56`

or

`rpm -Uvh --nodeps php-<version>.rpm`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  I try it many times but same error.

Comment: share the output of `rpm -qa php*`